# Is this possible? transparent png over slide revolution (clickable)

Tags: slider, png, transparent

I want two slide revolutions (or at least one), but with this skin over it:
[image]

The overlay image would be on top of the images, so clicking the gallery would be impossible (and the bullets to change image inside of it). I know about map coordinates, but it's a slider revolution, so it will not work in this case I think.

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

My HTML & CSS so far: [(JSFiddle)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/53j7rt9f/)

```html
<div class="thePNG"></div>
<div class="theSLIDERS">
    <div class="fakeSLIDER1">HEY' IM CLICKABLE</div>
    <div class="fakeSLIDER2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.thePNG {
    background-image: url(my-overlay-image.png);
    width: 787px;
    height: 610px;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
.theSLIDERS{
    margin-top: -600px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fakeSLIDER1{
    background-color: red;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.fakeSLIDER2{
    background-color: green;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: (ops I forgot to align the clickable text vertically in the middle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer!

its easy:

CSS: 
"pointer-events: none;"

!